# Have textbox update every 5 seconds PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtgui, qtcore

So here is my problem, I have data from a serial cable being read every 5 seconds and being stored on a CSV file. I am also taking that data and making it into a list. What I would like to do is take variables 5, 7, and 9 and have them be displayed in my GUI where I have Qtextboxes... how do I do that?

The list of variables will be in a value known as listvalues. I want to call 5, 7, and 9 and have them display in their respective text boxes in my PyQt window.

here is my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
import masimo
import csv
import time
import datetime as DT
import threading
from threading import Thread
import serial
import os

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\SpO2\Desktop\Data")
time = time.strftime("%d %b %Y %H%M%S")
location = r'%s.csv' % time
outputfile = open(location, mode='x', newline='')
outputWriter = csv.writer(outputfile)
outputWriter.writerow(["start"])
outputfile.close()
port = "COM4"


class ExampleApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, masimo.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

def SerialRead():
    delay1 = DT.datetime.now()                
    ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)   
    out = ser.read(167)
    reading = str(out)
    plaintext1 = reading.replace(' ', ', ')
    plaintext = plaintext1.replace('=', ', ')
    listvalue = plaintext.split(", ")
    ser.close()

    outputfile = open(location, mode='a', newline='')
    outputWriter = csv.writer(outputfile)
    outputWriter.writerow([plaintext])
    outputfile.close()

    delay2 = DT.datetime.now()
    differencetime = (delay2 - delay1).total_seconds()
    writedelay = int(5)
    restart = (writedelay - differencetime)
    threading.Timer(restart, SerialRead).start() 

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ExampleApp()
    QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = SerialRead).start()
    Thread(target = main).start()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think you could do one of two things:

1. Use a [QTimer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtimer.html) in your window, set its interval to 5 seconds and connect a method to its timeout signal, and update your text fields within that method.
2. Use a [threading event](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html#event-objects) that is shared between your window and your read process and use a QTimer in your window class that checks more frequently to see if the event is set and do the update when it is.

I would probably use an event so that you know that the thread is sleeping and you aren't trying to read values while the thread is writing them.

In your `ExampleApp` class, you would need to store the event and handle the timeouts:

```
class ExampleApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, masimo.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, event, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 
        self.dataWasReadEvent = event

        self.checkThreadTimer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.checkThreadTimer.setInterval(500) #.5 seconds

        self.checkThreadTimer.timeout.connect(self.readListValues)

    def readListValues(self):
        if self.dataWasReadEvent.is_set():
            #Read your events from the list and update your fields

            self.dataWasReadEvent.clear() #Clear the event set flag so that nothing happens the next time the timer times out
```

Your `SerialRead` function would need to take an argument that is the threading event and the event would need to be set after the serial read but before the restart:

```
def SerialRead(dataReadEvent):
    ...
    dataReadEvent.set()
    threading.Timer(restart, SerialRead, args=(dataReadEvent,)).start()
```

Your `main` function will also need to accept an event argument to be passed to the initializer for ExampleApp:

```
def main(dataReadEvent):
    ...
    form = ExampleApp(dataReadEvent)
```

And finally, in your `if __name__ == '__main__':` section, the threading event would need to be created and passed to the Thread calls:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataReadEvent = threading.Event()
    Thread(target = SerialRead, args=(dataReadEvent,) ).start()
    Thread(target = main, args=(dataReadEvent,) ).start()
```

Comment: OK... I sort of follow... how might I integrate this if my textbox objects name is "SPO2text" and the value I want printed in this box is variable #5 in 'Listvalues'

Comment: Is your text box a [QLineEdit](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html)? QLineEdit has a method `setText` that is used to set the text in the box. You would set the text to the fifth variable (index 4) with a call like: `self.SPO2text.setText(str(Listvalues[4]))`

Comment: They are QLineEdits. Awesome. I will report back on when I test it out!

Comment: I am getting this callback when I try to run script: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event' ... thoughts? @sid16rgt

Comment: My mistake. You will need to change the signature of the main() function to take a positional argument for the threading event and change the form = ExampleApp call to pass the event to the initializer. I will update my answer when I get on a computer.

Comment: I figured that was the case... can't quite seem to figure out how to put a 'pass' argument in properly.  ... I Also have 2 buttons in my UI (start and stop) how easy would it be to code them to start/stop these threads?

Comment: I've foraged the internet and come up dry... How do I implement a pass and initiate with multthreading? Thanks for all your help thus far!

Comment: Read up on thread synchronization. I read [this post](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm) many years ago and it got me started. Essentially your thread would skip reading until an event were set or it was able to acquire a lock or semaphore. Threading in Python is similar to other languages with the caveat being the Global Interpreter Lock which will only allow one thread to execute simultaneously.

Comment: thanks for the forward! I am rather new to this multi threading... Do you happen to know how to fix the issue I am having? I'm at a loss :(

Comment: You could make another event for the read thread and set or clear it from the buttons on the GUI by attaching methods to their clicked signal.

Comment: hahaha sorry, I meant for the 'missing 1 required positional argument' ... You had mentioned you would fix your answer to have working code hopefully :)

Comment: Ha. Yes, I just fixed the answer a few minutes ago and I think it should work.

Comment: awesome! I'll try in a bit... I'll also try to configure the buttons, might fail but at least I tried!

Comment: Tried the code... its recording fine to CSV every 5 seconds, starting the GUI fine, but still not updating the textboxes...

Comment: My bad, I put a capital letter where I shouldnt have. It all works now! Thanks!